# Grails Command object @PostConstruct or something?

Tags: grails, grails-controller

I want to initialize Command field from an injected Service.

So I need to execute a Command's method **after** it has been fully initialized, but **before** `params` is assigned to fields.

How can I do it? OK, I can get a Service bean by hand in constructor. Any better way?

Had no luck with `@PostConstruct` or `InitializingBean` - looks like Command is not a bean, right?

*Grails 1.3.5*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right the command is not a bean. You could instantiate the command instance by a service method and do initialization there and return the instance back to the controller. Than call the controller's bindData with the returned instance like this:

```
// controller code
def myService // injected

def action = {
    def command = mySerivce.createCommandInstance() 
    bindData(command, params)
}

// service code
class MyService {
    def createCommandInstance() {
       def cmd = new MyCommand()
       doSomeInitializationWithCommand(cmd)
       return cmd
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. As a last resort, I'd do this. Basically, this is re-creating a `Command` functionality by hand, as the `createCommandInstance()/bindData()` needs to be in every action. For now, I'll stick to accessing service beans via `ApplicationContext` in `Command` constructor - it adds extra code to Command, but won't repeat code over Controllers.